# How to invoke non-void function on window thread

Tags: c#, winforms

I was using

```
  Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => SendCommand(_monitorCmd, _monitorOutput)));
```

to launch `string SendCommand(string cmd, CommandOutput outputTo)` on main window thread but now I also need to read its return value. So I tried:

```
string rx = Invoke(new Func<string, CommandOutput, string>(
                    (c, m)=> SendCommand(cmd, _monitorOutput)
                    ));
```

It compiles but throws TargetParameterCountException.

I fixed it using a delegate:

```
Func<string, CommandOutput, string> del;
string rx = del.Invoke(cmd, _monitorOutput);
```

But, please, show me where is my error with the lambda code.

Comment: `string rx = (string)Invoke(new Func<string>(()=> SendCommand(cmd, _monitorOutput)));` or `string rx = Invoke(new Func<string, CommandOutput, string>((s, c)=> SendCommand(s, c)), cmd, _monitorOutput) as string;` etc.

Comment: I.e., the first one just defines the return Type, the values are passed directly as arguments to the method; the other all of them, the values are passed as a param array (could be boxed / unboxed, probably irrelevant here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a captured variable from inside the lambda

```cs
string rx = null;
Invoke(new Action(() => rx = SendCommand(cmd, _monitorOutput)));
```

Alternatively, you can use the `Delegate` overload, although this is likely to be much slower

```cs
string rx = (string) Invoke(
    new Func<string, CommandOutput, string>(SendCommand),
    _monitorCmd, _monitorOutput);
```

In this case the arguments must match the parameters *exactly*.